# Connection Salesforce with Amazon Connect Refused to display 'https://myInstance.awsapps.com/connect/ccp'

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, amazon

I have a problem. I'm doing the integration of Salesforce With Amazon Connect and I have an error in the console

> Refused to display 'https://myInstance.awsapps.com/connect/ccp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I followed all the instructions of [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/enabling-amazon-connect-with-salesforce-service-and-sales-cloud/) and also take into consideration [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_en/connect/latest/adminguide/salesforce-integration.html).

In the same way when I click on a phone number the phone does not open and the console gives me the error

> 'https://myInstance.awsapps.com/connect/ccp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

In session settings I have unchecked both of these options:

- Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers
- Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this today while integrating with Salesforce, nearly given up, it turns out that need to add the Virualforce page domain used in CCP control panel to the Connect Approved origins list.

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Frame-Options` header is being set by myInstance.awsapps.com domain.

This configuration tells the browser not to load this URL in an iframe.